# Swift UIImageView is always empty

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uiimage, viewcontroller

My UIImageView is always blank. When the image view is loaded I have it print the image and image view out. This is the output from the print in first section of code: **UIImage: 0x170898010>, {4032, 3024}
UIImageView: 0x14bb077e0; frame = (0 64; 375 554);** This is the output from the print in second section of code: **autoresize = RM+BM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = CALayer: 0x170a31240** It seems to be storing the image but it does not appear.

Here is where the image, which is saved correctly to CloudKit is downloaded and converted:

```
if let asset = record["Picture"] as? CKAsset,
       let data = NSData(contentsOf: asset.fileURL),
       let image1 = UIImage(data: data as Data)
       {
           let eventPageViewController:EventPageViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "EventPage") as! EventPageViewController
           eventPageViewController.toPass = image1
           print(image1)
       }
```

Here is the code for the ViewController that displays the UIImageView:

```
class EventPageViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var eventPic: UIImageView!
    var toPass: UIImage!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        eventPic.image = toPass
        print(eventPic)
    }
```

here is where the eventPageViewController appears:

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, annotationView view: MKAnnotationView, calloutAccessoryControlTapped control: UIControl) {

        let eventPageViewController:EventPageViewController = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "EventPage") as! EventPageViewController

        self.present(eventPageViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

Comment: did you check if image is passed as not nil? in your viewDidLoad? try to do initialization of it in viewWillAppear

Comment: I get the same output and result @EugeneZhenyaGordin

Comment: what about checking if it's not nil there, have you checked ?

Comment: its not nil. It prints the same output

Comment: if you try and add some image in your viewDIdLoad from your asset lib there, can you see it?

Comment: yes I can @EugeneZhenyaGordin

Comment: I pretty much do the same things in code, except I set the image in **viewWillAppear**. I know @EugeneZhenyaGordin asked if you tried this, but I wanted to make sure - viewDidLoad usually fires only on the first segue. viewWillAppear fires every segue. Move that one line (eventPic.image = toPass) to that override.

Comment: I tried and I still get the same print and a blank view @dfd

Comment: Last question, then I'm at a loss for the issue. I didn't catch this before, but your second print addresses the UIImageView, not the UIImage (which the first print does). Could you change that to **print(toPass)** instead? It really sounds like it'll be nil.

Comment: toPass is nill @dfd

Comment: Ok. I lied. :-) One final question - are you segueing to EventPageViewController? If so, the maybe post the *full* segue call because that's where the issue is. If not, I can't help you - all I've used in these cases are segues.

Comment: I added another function at the bottom of my question. Is this correct? @dfd

Comment: It could be, but it's not using a segue. I'm not tapped out of suggestions and questions. Good luck figuring out what the issue is. All I'm left with is timing... the source VC has the image, the destination VC doesn't - and the image is (a)  being passed *before* that instance is presented, or (b) a different instance is being presented.

Comment: would you know how to solve this problem using a segue? @dfd

Comment: I'll post it as an answer. If it helps, great!

Answer (score 0):

From Apple docs about image property:

> This property is set to the image you specified at initialization time. If you did not use the init(image:) or init(image:highlightedImage:) method to initialize your image view, the initial value of this property is nil.

https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiimageview/1621069-image

Comment: If I was downloading multiply pictures at the same time, how could each be assigned to a pin on the map where you on see the picture on the next screen if the annotation is clicked. I need to be able to assign the image for later. @wetsweater

Answer (score 0):

The OP isn't using segues, but I was asked if this would solve things. Here's my description and code that works using a segue.

Baseline:

My app has two view controllers (select and edit) with a segue between them (ShowEditView). That is **all** I've defined in IB. Everything else is in code.

There is one difference that appears to not be at issue - I use a UIImagePickerController to get the image where the OP pulls it from the assets. *This doesn't appear to be at issue because the source VC has the image.* So picking it up from here (two VCs with a segue defined in IB, the image in a UIImage instance) here's how I might code things based on the OP's code.

In the source VC:

```
func imageAttained() {

    // here's where you move the image into image1

    // this is the segue - make sure you've named it in IB
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "ShowEventView", sender: self)
}

// this is an override in the source VC and passes the image

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "ShowEventView" {
        if let vc = segue.destination as? EventPageViewController {
            vc.toPass = image1
        }
    }
}
```

And in the destination VC (EventPageViewController):

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    eventPic.image = toPass
}
```